# flutterでカラーコードをFirebaseに保存したい

Tags: flutter, dart

Flutter（Dart）でカラーコード(Color(0xff000000))をFireStoreに保存したいのですが、どのように保存すればよいでしょうか。

具体的な流れとしては、初期値としてColor(0xff000000)を与え、カラーピッカーなどを用いてユーザーに色を選択してもらい、その色を保存したいです。

ご教授お願いいたします

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`value` プロパティで int 型にして保存するのはどうでしょうか？
保存した値は `Color(int value)` コンストラクタに渡すことで、`Color` に戻すことができます。

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Color/value.html
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Color/Color.html

```
final color = Color(0xDD13D582);
// color.value である 3709064578 を保存する。

// 保存した値を Color へ変換する。
Color(3709064578)
```

もしくは16進数表記した String として保存するのも良いと思います。

```
final color = Color(0xDD13D582);
// color.value.toRadixString(16) である "dd13d582" を保存する。

// 保存した値を Color へ変換する。
Color(int.parse('dd13d582', radix: 16))
```